# ngIf is not working on getting value from radio buttons

Tags: angular, angular-material, angular-material2

```html
<form #userForm="ngForm" (ngSubmit)="onSubmit(userForm)" style="background-color:#F4F6F7;border:1px solid black">
                            <fieldset>
                                <md-radio-group class="pull-left" style="margin:10px">

                                    <md-radio-button #ship style="font-size:13px">Pickup in the store!</md-radio-button><br>
                                    <table>
                                        <tr>
                                            <span style="font-size:10px;margin:25px">(Ready in as little as 1 hour)</span></tr>
                                        <tr>
                                            <select placeholder="Pick here" *ngIf="ship.checked" style="margin-left:25px;width:100%">
                                                <option *ngFor="let data of objArray" [value]="data">
                                                    {{ data}}
                                                </option>
                                            </select>
                                        </tr>
                                    </table>

                                    <br>
                                    <md-radio-button #ship1 value="true2" style="font-size:13px">Ship</md-radio-button><br>
                                    <table>
                                        <tr> <span style="font-size:10px;margin:25px">(3-5 Business Days)</span></tr>
                                        <tr><select placeholder="Pick here" *ngIf="ship1.checked" style="margin-left:25px">
                                        <option *ngFor="let data of objArray" [value]="data">
                                            {{ data}}
                                        </option>
                                    </select></tr>
                                    </table>
                                    <br>
                                    <md-radio-button #ship2 style="font-size:13px">Schedule a Delivery</md-radio-button><br>
                                    <table>
                                        <tr> <span style="font-size:10px;margin:25px">(Enter 5 digit ZIP code of the delivery address)</span></tr>
                                        <tr>
                                            <md-form-field class="example-full-width" *ngIf="ship2.checked" style="margin-left:25px"> <input mdInput placeholder="ZIP code" name="zipcode"></md-form-field><br></tr>
                                    </table>
                                    <br>

                                </md-radio-group>
                                <br>
                            </fieldset>
                        </form>
```

Iam working in ecommerce site.Here I need to show a modal containing 3 radio buttons.On selection of the radio button,select options should be appear regarding to that radio button.I have used radio button value in the ngIf condition.But it is not working and the select options are appearing without choosing radio button.
Below is my code:

```js
import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';
import {Http,Response,Headers, RequestOptions} from '@angular/http';
import { Router} from '@angular/router';
import * as _ from "lodash";
import { PaginationService } from '../../pagination.service';
import { WooApiService } from 'ng2woo';
import { NgForm } from '@angular/forms';
import {
    ReactiveFormsModule,
    FormsModule,
    FormGroup,
    FormControl,
    Validators,
    FormBuilder,
} from '@angular/forms';


@Component({
  selector: 'app-home',
  templateUrl: './home.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./home.component.css']
})
export class HomeComponent implements OnInit {
    public productsList=[];
public productArr=[];
    public objArray: Array<string> = ["Albania", "Andorra", "Armenia", "Austria", "Azerbaijan"];
total:any;  
    currentPage:Number;
constructor(private http:Http,private router:Router,private woo: WooApiService) {     
  }
createAuthorizationHeader(headers: Headers) {
    headers.append('Authorization', 'Basic ' +
      btoa('ck_543700d9f8c08268d75d3efefb302df4fad70a8f:cs_f1514261bbe154d662eb5053880d40518367c901')); 
    headers.append("Content-Type", "application/json");
  }   
    getData(){

     let headers = new Headers();
     this.createAuthorizationHeader(headers);
return this.http.get("https://www.colourssoftware.com/wordpress/wp-json/wc/v2/products?page=1&per_page=10",{
        headers:headers
        })
      .subscribe(data => { 
        const products=data.json();
          console.log(data.headers);

     this.total = data.headers.get('X-WP-TotalPages');
    console.log("Pages ",this.total);

           for( var i=1;i<=this.total;i++){
    console.log("hello "+this.total);
    this.getProducts(i);
    }
           console.log("hello"+JSON.stringify(this.productsList));
          this.dataArr();
    },
err => {
    console.log("Error!: ",err);
}
        );
       

    }   
getProducts(i){ 
    this.currentPage=i;
    console.log("cpage "+this.currentPage);
    let headers = new Headers();
    this.createAuthorizationHeader(headers);
return this.http.get("https://www.colourssoftware.com/wordpress/wp-json/wc/v2/products?per_page=10&page="+this.currentPage,{
        headers:headers
        })
      .subscribe(data => { 
          const products = data.json();
          this.productsList.push(data.json());
          console.log("hello"+JSON.stringify(this.productsList));
        },
err => {
    console.log("Error!: ",err);
}
        ); 

 } 
dataArr(){
    console.log("array"+this.productsList.length);
for(var i=0;i<this.productsList.length;i++){
    this.productArr.push(this.productsList[i]);
     console.log("arr"+this.productArr);
}
   
}

  ngOnInit() {
      this.getData();  
  }

}
```

```html
 <form #userForm="ngForm" (ngSubmit)="onSubmit(userForm)" style="background-color:#F4F6F7;border:1px solid black">
                            <fieldset>
                                <md-radio-group class="pull-left" style="margin:10px">

                                    <md-radio-button [(ngModel)]="store" name="store" value="true1" style="font-size:13px">Pickup in the store!</md-radio-button><br>
                                    <span style="font-size:10px;margin:25px">(Ready in as little as 1 hour)</span><br>
                                    <select placeholder="Pick here" *ngIf="store==true1">
                                        <option *ngFor="let data of objArray" [value]="data" style="z-index:1">
                                            {{ data}}
                                        </option>
                                    </select>
                                    <md-radio-button [(ngModel)]="ship" name="ship" value="true2" style="font-size:13px">Ship</md-radio-button><br>
                                    <span style="font-size:10px;margin:25px">(3-5 Business Days)</span>
                                    <select placeholder="Pick here" *ngIf="ship==true2">
                                        <option *ngFor="let data of objArray" [value]="data" style="z-index:1">
                                            {{ data}}
                                        </option>
                                    </select>

                                    <br>
                                    <md-radio-button [(ngModel)]="delivery" name="delivery" value="true3" style="font-size:13px">Schedule a Delivery</md-radio-button><br>
                                    <span style="font-size:10px;margin:25px">(Enter 5 digit ZIP code of the delivery address)</span>
                                    <br>
                                    <md-form-field class="example-full-width" *ngIf="delivery==true3"> <input mdInput placeholder="ZIP code" name="zipcode"></md-form-field><br>
                                </md-radio-group>
                                <br>
```

Why ngIf is not working?Where I did the mistake?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Instead of doing this `[(ngModel)]="ship" name="ship" value="true2"`, give your `<md-radio-button>` an id e.g. `#ship`. The you can check `ship.checked` in `*ngIf` like this:

```
<md-radio-button #ship style="font-size:13px">Ship</md-radio-button><br>
<span style="font-size:10px;margin:25px">(3-5 Business Days)</span>
<select placeholder="Pick here" *ngIf="ship.checked">
    <option *ngFor="let data of objArray" [value]="data" style="z-index:1">
        {{ data}}
    </option>
</select>
```

Do the same with other radio buttons as well. Link to [**stackblitz demo**](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-material2-beta-ypquyu?file=app/app.component.html).

Comment: It's working but defaultely two radio buttons are enabled.I need only one to be enabled at first

Comment: You must be doing something wrong. You need to give a different id for each radio button.

Comment: yeah,I have given different ids only

Comment: share your html code in this demo: https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-material2-beta-avz3tb?file=app/app.component.html

Comment: You have to give value to each of your radio buttons, and set the first one as checked like: `[checked]="true"` ... link to demo: https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-material2-beta-avz3tb?file=app/app.component.html